# Select particular rows from inside groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   group  level
0      1     10
1      1     10
2      1     11
3      2      5
4      2      5
5      3      9
6      3      9
7      3      9
8      3      8
```

The desired output is this:

```
   group  level
0      1     10
5      3      9
```

Namely, this is the logic: look inside each group, if there is more than 1 distinct value present in the `level` column, return the first row in that group. For example, no row from group `2` is selected, because the only value present in the `level` column is `5`.

In addition, how does the situation change if I want the last, instead of the first row of such groups?

What I have attempted was combining `group_by` statements, with creating sets from entries in the `level` column, but failed to produce anything even nearly sensible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with `groupby` and using `apply` to run a simple function on each group:

```
def get_first_val(group):
    has_multiple_vals = len(group['level'].unique()) >= 2
    if has_multiple_vals:
        return group['level'].loc[group['level'].first_valid_index()]
    else:
        return None

df.groupby('group').apply(get_first_val).dropna()
Out[8]: 
group
1    10
3     9
dtype: float64
```

There's also a `last_valid_index()` method, so you wouldn't have to
make any huge changes to get the last row instead.

If you have other columns that you want to keep, you just need a slight tweak:

```
import numpy as np
df['col1'] = np.random.randint(10, 20, 9)
df['col2'] = np.random.randint(20, 30, 9)
df
Out[17]: 
   group  level  col1  col2
0      1     10    19    21
1      1     10    18    24
2      1     11    14    23
3      2      5    14    26
4      2      5    10    22
5      3      9    13    27
6      3      9    16    20
7      3      9    18    26
8      3      8    11    2

def get_first_val_keep_cols(group):
    has_multiple_vals = len(group['level'].unique()) >= 2
    if has_multiple_vals:
        return group.loc[group['level'].first_valid_index(), :]
    else:
        return None

df.groupby('group').apply(get_first_val_keep_cols).dropna()
Out[20]: 
       group  level  col1  col2
group                          
1          1     10    19    21
3          3      9    13    27
```

Comment: How do I make sure other columns are maintained, supposing the original dataframe has col1, col2, col3 that I still want to remain as part of the result?

Comment: This mysteriously does not work for me. With the previous approach, I got the right results, only missing some columns, now I am getting an empty dataframe. Perhaps here return group.loc[group['level'].first_valid_index(), :] without , ?

Answer (score 1):

This would be simpler:

```
In [121]:

print df.groupby('group').\
          agg(lambda x: x.values[0] if (x.values!=x.values[0]).any() else np.nan).\
           dropna()

       level
group       
1         10
3          9
```

For each group, if any of the values are not the same as the first value, aggregate that group into its first value; otherwise, aggregate it to `nan`.

Finally, `dropna()`.